# Apache rewrite string in URL - obstacle is "?" in query

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Want to rewrite an URL with a given user-prefix ("u-") from

```
https://example.com/access/check?user=u-abc&pass=123
```

to an URL without the prefix:

```
https://example.com/access/check?user=abc&pass=123
```

I tried several rules, e.g

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^access/check?user=u-(.*)$ check?user=$1
```

I am stuck with the "?"

IF the rewrite had to apply to slightly the same, but without the "?", it indeed works:

```
https://example.com/access/checkuser=u-abc&pass=123

RewriteRule ^access/checkuser=u-(.*)$ checkuser=$1
```

and provides the expected outcome (without the user-prefix "u-")

```
checkuser=abc&pass=123
```

I tried to match the "?" with [?] or \x3F, and applied the QSA flag as described on [mod_rewrite.org](http://mod-rewrite.org/book/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) , but still not succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is not part of the [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched) pattern

> **What is matched?**
>
> - ...
> - If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

So in your case, you must check against `QUERY_STRING` and use the replacement `%1` instead of `$1`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} user=u-(.*)
RewriteRule ^access/check$ /access/check?user=%1 [L]
```

Comment: great, worked for me, and thanks for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 2):

To match a "?" which is a query string, you need a RewriteCond, query strings can't be matched with a RewriteRule alone.

By definition a query string is everything after the "?", and you can use them in destination of a RewriteRule but to match them you will need a RewriteCond as I just mentioned.

Example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=u-(.*)
RewriteRule ^access/check check?user=%1
```

Note captured groups from RewriteCond are referred to with the % symbol.

Play a bit with simple examples and try out.

Comment: Thanks! Just to complete your example in order to provide the expected output: RewriteRule ^access/check access/check?user=%1

Answer (score 2):

QueryString is not part of match in Rule's pattern, you need to match against **%{QUERY_STRING}** using RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=u-([^&]+)&pass=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^access/check/?$ /access/check/?user=%1&pass=%2 [L]
```

Comment: There was only a minor glitch, with one "/" too much, therefor -> RewriteRule ^access/check/?$ /access/check?user=%1&pass=%2 [L]