# Rewrite rule based on QUERY_STRING

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect the url

www.mydomain.com/index.php?route=first/second to www.mydomain.com/second 
I have tried the following rules but none seem to work

```
   RewriteEngine On
1) RewriteRule ^index.php?route=first/second$ /second [R=301,L]
2) RewriteRule ^index.php?route=first/second$ www.mydomain.com/second [R=301,L]
3) Redirect ^index.php?route=first/second /second/
4) Redirect ^index.php?route=first/second www.mydomain.com/second/
5) Redirect ^www.mydomain.com/index.php?route=first/second /second/
6) Redirect ^www.mydomain.com/index.php?route=first/second www.mydomain.com/second/
```

However the below rule works:
`RewriteRule ^second$ /index.php?route=first/second [R=301,L]`
 but point 1 and 2 above does not work

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @Sahil your rewrite condition and rule is redirecting to http://www.example.com/index.php/second?route=first/second not http://www.example.com/second

Comment: Maybe this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/42953529/1741542

Answer (score 0):

make sure you put `RewriteEngine On` before any of the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure: `index.php` exists, else for that we have to set some condition for `file existence` as well like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} route=first/second
RewriteRule .* /second? [R,L]
```